# Why is my C++ program generating nonsense math?

Tags: c++

My program is below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b; 
    int c;
    double perimeter = (a + b + c);
    int s=0.5*(a + b + c);

    cout << "Enter three numbers for the lengths of a triangle with sides a, b, and c. The first number should be the smallest, and the last should be the longest.";
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;

    cout << "Lengths " ;
    cout << a; 
    cout << " " ;
    cout << b; 
    cout << " ";
    cout << c;

    cout << "The perimeter of the triangle is ";
    cout << perimeter ;

    cout << "s equals " ;
    cout << s;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Enter three numbers for the lengths of a triangle with sides a, b, and c.  The first number should be the smallest, and the last should be the longest.
1
2
3
Lengths 1 2 3
The perimeter of the triangle is 32061
s equals 16030
```

Last I checked, 1 + 2 + 3 does not equal 32061.  What is happening, and how can I fix this?

//I am guessing it's because I do not have the proper heading //(#somethingoranother)?
//Or I haven't declared it? but I don't know how.
//I recall using sqrt to find roots in the past as a function without

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0; 
    int c = 0;
    double area = 0;
    double sqrt=0;


      cout << "Enter three numbers for the lengths of a triangle with sides a, b, and c.  The first number should be the smallest, and the last should ne the longest.";
      cin >> a;
      cin >> b;
      cin >> c;

    int perimeter = (a + b + c);
    int s=0.5*(a + b + c);

    area = sqrt ( s*(s - a)*(s - b)*(s - c) );


     cout << "The perimeter of the triangle is ";
      cout << perimeter ;
      cout << "." ;

      cout << " s equals " ;
      cout << s; 
      cout << ".  ";

      cout << "Area is ";
      cout << area;

    }
```

just entering a long formula for "area =" but the computer doesn't seem to like  that either

Comment: Last I checked you don't write your expressions with uninitialized variables. The two statements are executed immediately, not when you refer to `perimeter` or `s`.

Comment: You're calculating the perimeter before setting a, b, and c so they have undefined values so perimeter and s have undefined values. Move the lines to calculate perimeter and s after the "cin" lines so that the values for a, b, and c are set.

Comment: You need to enable more compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code. The `perimeter` and `s` computation need to happen after you initialize values for the sides of your triangle.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b; 
    int c;

    cout << "Enter three numbers for the lengths of a triangle with sides a, b, and c. The first number should be the smallest, and the last should be the longest.";
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;

    cout << "Lengths " ;
    cout << a; 
    cout << " " ;
    cout << b; 
    cout << " ";
    cout << c;

    double perimeter = (a + b + c);
    int s=0.5*(a + b + c);

    cout << "The perimeter of the triangle is ";
    cout << perimeter ;

    cout << "s equals " ;
    cout << s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding together uninitialized values. You need to fill in a, b and c before doing math on them. Right now the way you're doing it is resulting in random values being added together, which is why you're getting nonsense results.

Comment: I wondered if that might be the cause, but when I initialize the values by replaing int a; above with int a =0; I the lose the ability to enter a value for a etc. once the program is running.  So either I am not initializing the variables properly or something else is also wrong.

Comment: No you don't. Just do what vk239 suggested - declare the variables above, then fill them in with `cin`, then add the values together and store the result in a new variable, and finally print out that new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Move the computations to the proper spot in the program: after you know the imput numberes, but before you print them out:

```
cout << "Enter three numbers for the lengths of a triangle with sides a, b, and c.  The first number should be the smallest, and the last should be    the longest.";
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
cin >> c;

double perimeter = (a + b + c);
int s=0.5*(a + b + c);

cout << "Lengths " ;
...
```